# how to put files in folder with their prefix name?

Tags: 16.04

I have thousands of files in one folder I want to put files with the same prefix in a folder named with the same name as the prefix.

```
   -folder
      -a_1.txt
      -a_2.txt
      -a_3.txt
      -b_1.txt
      -b_2.txt
      -b_3.txt
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
   -a
     -1.txt
     -2.txt
     -3.txt
   -b
     -1.txt
     -2.txt
     -3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find -exec`:

```
find folder -name "*.txt" \
    -exec sh -c 'f="$(basename "$1")"; mkdir -p "${f%%_*}"; mv "$1" "${f%%_*}"/"${f#*_}"' find-sh {} \;
```

If you have multiple `_` in the filename. This will cut after the first `_`.
Swap `f%%` + `f#` to `f%` + `f##` if you want to cut after the last `_` instead.

Comment: Voting for this answer: it is simpler, shorter and faster!

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prefix length of the file in chars 1...x 
PREFIXLENGTH=1

for file in *.txt
do  
    # define the folder name
    prefix=${file:0:$PREFIXLENGTH}

    # always mkdir here and fetch the error message
    # can also be made with an if..then     
    mkdir $prefix 2>/dev/null

    # split the rest of the file and move it to folder
    mv "$file" "$prefix/${file:$PREFIXLENGTH}"
done
```

Calling it in the directory of your filelist it gives then:

```
$ ls a b
a:
    _1.txt  _2.txt  _3.txt

b:
    _1.txt  _2.txt  _3.txt
```

Comment: thank you but it makes the directories but the files are not moved to them.It show this msg: "mv: target 'done' is not a directory"

Comment: You need to delete the "done" in the line "mv $file...". Copy & paste issue.

Comment: `for file in $(echo *.txt)` breaks on filenames with spaces. Use just `for file in *.txt`.

Comment: Well, partly right: I also have to set $file in " in the mv cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python script that moves a_1.txt, a_2.txt, a_3.txt to a folder named a and moves b_1.txt, b_3.txt to a folder named b, but it keeps the names as they are:

```
# Import the needed packages
import glob
import shutil
import os
import re
import sys

def copy_(file_path, dest):
    try:
        # get the prfix from the filepath
        pref = re.search(r'(.*)_\d*', file_path).group(1)
        # Check if the folder already exists and create it if not
        if not os.path.exists(dest + '/' + pref.split('/')[-1]):
            os.makedirs(dest + '/' + pref.split('/')[-1])
        # copy the file to the folder
        shutil.move(file_path,
                     dest + '/' + pref.split('/')[-1] + '/' + file_path.split('/')[-1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('there was a problem copying {} to the directory'.format(file_path))
        pass

# Set the directory containing the folders
dirname = sys.argv[1]
# Set the directory that you want to create the folders in
dest = sys.argv[2]
for filepath in glob.glob(dirname + '/**'):
    copy_(filepath, dest)
```

To run the script, save it to `file.py` then run it using `python file.py dir1 dir2` where dir1 is the folder where your files exist and dir2 is folder where you want to save the new folders

**Before:**

```
dir1
├── a_1.txt
├── a_2.txt,
├── a_3.txt
├── b_1.txt
├── b_2.txt,
└── b_3.txt
```

**After:**

```
dir2
├── a
│   ├── a_1.txt
│   ├── a_2.txt,
│   └── a_3.txt
└── b
    ├── b_1.txt
    ├── b_2.txt,
    └── b_3.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I need a ubuntu command.

Comment: Please check pLumo's answer, if it works for you, accept it.